# How do you make a storage reference in swift for Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

How do you create a field of type storage reference in the swift dictionary format using swift. I keep on getting an error saying that FIRStorageReference.
This is the code below, photoRef is a storage reference:

```
        let newFirePhotoRef = newUserRef.collection("Photos").document()
    photoRef = photoRef.child(newFirePhotoRef.documentID)

    newFirePhotoRef.setData([
        "Date":Date(),
        "Photo Reference in Storage": photoRef 
        ])
```

This is the error I receive:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: FIRStorageReference (found in field `Photo Reference in Storage`)'

Comment: The error message says what exactly?  Using which API call?

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add a storage Reference in swift for Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066107/how-do-you-add-a-storage-reference-in-swift-for-firestore)