# How do you add a storage Reference in swift for Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

How do you create a field of type storage reference in the swift dictionary format using swift. I keep on getting an error saying that FIRStorageReference. Thank you in advance for your help.
This is the code below, photoRef is a storage reference:

```
let newFirePhotoRef = newUserRef.collection("Photos").document()
photoRef = photoRef.child(newFirePhotoRef.documentID)

newFirePhotoRef.setData([
  "Date":Date(),
  "Photo Reference in Storage": photoRef 
])
```

This is the error I receive:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: FIRStorageReference (found in field `Photo Reference in Storage`)'

I would like to create this field in swift 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't store objects of type FIRStorageReference in Firestore.  Instead, convert the FIRStorageReference object to a string, and store the string.  You could use some combination of [bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/FIRStorageReference#bucket) and [fullPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/FIRStorageReference#fullpath) to build a string that suits your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to add a value of type reference using a swift dictionary https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types, Ive seen on the Firestore console you can manually select type reference that appears to be an object containing two fields Database and Document path, the Database portion is automatically filled in with a URL to the storage bucket. Is it possible to create this field in swift.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you have a new question that's different than the first, please take some time to format a whole new question, which can have it own answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to create store a value of type reference in Firestore using a swift dictionary

Comment: Like I said, you can't put storage references objects in Firestore. You have to convert them to strings.  If you're wondering about a different type of reference, ask a different question explaining what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
//this is to store reference 
let ref =  db.document("listing/v4/content/\(key)")

let dataToWriteInFireStore :[String:Any] = [
   "_ref": ref,
   "id": 4,
   "timestamp": Int(Date().millisecondsSince1970)
]

db.collection("user_favs/v4/\(FIRUserID)").document("user_fav").setData(dataToWiteInFireStore) {
    err in
    if let err = err {
       print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
       print("Document successfully written!")
    }

   }
```